# How do I select all outermost features

Tags: qgis

Is there anyway in QGIS that I can select all the outermost features on a map? On an island that would be all that have a coastline.

edit: This is what I'm trying to select:
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? And preferably add an illustration to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Qgis, but in Arcmap I would create a large polygon enclosing all your features. Then I'd use [Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000) to create holes in that polygon where your features are. Finally I'd select those of your features that share a border with the enclosing polygon, which now is not overlapping your features, with [Select by location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000072000000) and *Boundary touches* as argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a copy of your polygon file. Start editing and use *Merge selected features* (*Advanced digitizing toolbar*) to create one polygon (sorry, I do not have an English QGIS so menu names may vary).
   [image]
2. Convert polygon (from step 1) to line using *Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon to Line*
3. Use *Vector > Spatial Query* to select all parcels which *intersects* line file.
   [image]